# how to avoid duplicates for unique Id's with timestamp

Tags: sql

Hi I have a situation like i am inserting a unique value into Data Base along with primary key 
by generating in java code. This unique Id has time stamp Ex:'`BatchID16Jul1411111111`'. where it is extended up to milliseconds.Now if two users hit at same time same unique ids are generated.

Is there any way to make this times tamp unique even it is called at same time.

Is it possible by getting auto increment number from DB.

Can any one suggest me solution for this situation.

Thanks in advance

Mahesh

Comment: why did you decide to use timetastamp as Unique ID rather than GUID???

Comment: Why can't you use a primary key with Auto Increment?

Comment: Can you use a compound primary key made up of your current primary key and whatever time stamp is generated? This is assuming your primary key is guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get an auto-incremented number from the database.  The exact syntax depends on the database.  These typically use one of three methods:

- An `auto-increment` declaration in the `create table` statement;
- An `identity` declaration in the `create table` statement; or,
- A sequence assigned as a default value to the primary key column.

Note, though, that the auto-incremented number will not have any meaning.  So, you will need a separate column for the `'BatchId`' and for the date time.